# Need help passing a QString value from one screen to another in QT

Tags: qt, signals-slots

Hey there i'm brand new to QT and only have some basic understanding of C++ behind me, but i'm struggling to pass the username QString variable from mainWindow.cpp to customerLogin.cpp. I've tried passing it through the constructor but that doesnt seem to work, and I'm struggling to understand how slots work.

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    if (!connOpen())
        ui->Status->setText("Failed to open the database");
    else
        ui->Status->setText("Database Conneceted...");
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::buttonLogin()
{
    QString username = ui->lineUser->text();
    QString password = ui->linePassword->text();

    if (!connOpen())
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed To Open the Database";
    }

    connOpen();
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("select * from owner where userid='"+username +"' and password='"+password +"' and rank='3'");

    if (qry.exec())
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (qry.next())
        {
            count++;
        }
        if(count ==1)
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this, "Login", "Username and password is correct");
            hide();
            connClose();
            customerLogin *userLogin = new customerLogin();
            userLogin->show();
        }
        else if (count != 1)
        {
            if(qry.exec("select * from owner where userid='"+username +"' and password='"+password +"' and rank='1'"))
            {
            int count = 0;
            while (qry.next())
            {
                count++;
            }
            if(count ==1)
            {
                QMessageBox::information(this, "Login", "Username and password is correct");
                hide();
                connClose();
                secAdminLogin *adminLogin = new secAdminLogin;
                adminLogin -> show();
            }
                else
                {
                    QMessageBox::warning(this,"Login", "Username and password is not correct!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**customerLogin.cpp**

```
customerLogin::customerLogin(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::customerLogin)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


}


customerLogin::~customerLogin()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created customerLogin you can add a function to pass the username from MainWindow.cpp like so.

```
customerLogin *userLogin = new customerLogin();
userLogin->setUsername(username);
userLogin->show();
```

You need to add this function to the .h and .cpp of customerLogin.

**customerLogin.h**

```
private:
QString m_username;

public:
void setUsername(QString username);
```

**customerLogin.cpp**

```
void customerLogin::setUsername(QString username)
{
    m_username = username;
}
```

Also you are calling connOpen() twice with

```
if (!connOpen())
{
    qDebug() << "Failed To Open the Database";
}
connOpen();
```

cause if(!connOpen()) will run the function and if it fails it will print debug message otherwice it has succeeded. And below you are calling it again which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the method suggested by bio, you can declare a global variable in MainWindow.cpp, and declare it as 'extern' in customerLogin.cpp to make it accessible.

For communicating 'username' thru signal/slot,

- declare a signal with one QString parameter in MainWindow.h
- declare a slot with one QString parameterin in customerLogin.h
- connect the signal and slot after customerLogin object is created
- emit the signal with 'username' variable as parameter whenever you want (in this case, before userLogin->show(); )